# Android Key Generation for getting map

Tags: android

I am new in android and want to get a key for google map but unable to generate key from Google developer Console,I already have SHA1 key.Please Suggest the right path.

Comment: You can search, there are so many answers available for it.

Comment: Try here : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [official link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/), click Get A Key and follow the instructions.
**Try to google firstly before asking.**